# R - Making loops faster

Tags: performance, r

This little code snippet is supposed to loop through a sorted data frame.  It keeps a count of how many successive rows have the same information in columns aIndex and cIndex and also bIndex and dIndex.  If these are the same, it deposits the count and increments it for the next time around, and if they differ, it deposits the count and resets it to 1 for the next time around.

```
for (i in 1:nrow(myFrame)) {
  if (myFrame[i, aIndex] == myFrame[i, cIndex] &
    myFrame[i, bIndex] == myFrame[i, dIndex]) {
      myFrame[i, eIndex] <- count
      count <- (count + 1)
  } else {
      myFrame[i, eIndex] <- count
      count <- 1
  }
}
```

It's been running for a long time now.  I understand that I'm supposed to vectorize whenever possible, but I'm not really seeing it here.  What am I supposed to do to make this faster?

Here's what an example few rows should look like after running:

```
aIndex bIndex cIndex dIndex eIndex
     1      2      1      2      1
     1      2      1      2      2
     1      2      4      8      3
     4      8      1      4      1
     1      4      1      4      1
```

Comment: Should have said: the dataframe is ~300k rows big.

Comment: Chase was asking for a snippet of your data `myFrame` so that we can see its structure and run your code you provided.  Without that its much more difficult to help.

Comment: @DanielCates: I believe Chase means a sample of the `myFrame` object.

Comment: Is `eIndex` right? The third row doesn't seem to be right as neither of your conditions are true (`aIndex != cIndex` and `bIndex != `dIndex`)

Comment: The third row should be right because it should put `count` there before setting it back to 1.  Also, how am I supposed to go about giving a sample of the object?

Comment: You can copy the output of `dput(myFrame)` or a subset of it `dput(myFrame[1:100,])`.  Or make a sample set of data.

Comment: I also think that rows 1 and 2 should be grouped in 1 row with a èIndex`equals to 3.

Comment: Ah, the point is that there are many other columns that might differ and I need that information, too.  I'll have to make a sample set of data, hold on...

Answer (score 2):

I think this will do what you want; the tricky part is that the count resets *after* the difference, which effectively puts a shift on the `eIndex`.

There (hopefully) is an easier way to do this, but this is what I came up with.

```
tmprle <- rle(((myFrame$aIndex == myFrame$cIndex) & 
               (myFrame$bIndex == myFrame$dIndex)))
myFrame$eIndex <- c(1,
                    unlist(ifelse(tmprle$values, 
                                  Vectorize(seq.default)(from = 2,
                                                         length = tmprle$lengths), 
                                  lapply(tmprle$lengths, 
                                         function(x) {rep(1, each = x)})))
                    )[-(nrow(myFrame)+1)]
```

which gives

```
> myFrame
  aIndex bIndex cIndex dIndex eIndex
1      1      2      1      2      1
2      1      2      1      2      2
3      1      2      4      8      3
4      4      8      1      4      1
5      1      4      1      4      1
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this will work. I have reworked the `rle` and `sequence` bits.

```
dat <- read.table(text="aIndex bIndex cIndex dIndex
1 2 1 2
1 2 1 2
1 2 4 8
4 8 1 4
1 4 1 4", header=TRUE, as.is=TRUE,sep = " ")
dat$eIndex <-NA
#identify rows where a=c and b=d, multiply by 1 to get a numeric vector
dat$id<-(dat$aIndex==dat$cIndex & dat$bIndex==dat$dIndex)*1
#identify sequence
runs <- rle(dat$id)
#create sequence, multiply by id to keep only identicals, +1 at the end
count <-sequence(runs$lengths)*dat$id+1
#shift sequence down one notch, start with 1
dat$eIndex <-c(1,count[-length(count)])
dat

  aIndex bIndex cIndex dIndex eIndex id
1      1      2      1      2      1  1
2      1      2      1      2      2  1
3      1      2      4      8      3  0
4      4      8      1      4      1  0
5      1      4      1      4      1  1
```

Comment: That does work for my extended example as well (`dat<-structure(list(aIndex = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
4L), bIndex = c(2L, 2L, 2L, 8L, 4L, 2L, 5L, 7L, 4L, 1L), cIndex = c(1L, 
1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L), dIndex = c(2L, 2L, 8L, 4L, 
4L, 2L, 1L, 8L, 2L, 2L), eIndexExpected = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L)), .Names = c("aIndex", "bIndex", "cIndex", 
"dIndex", "eIndexExpected"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-10L))`)